# 3-Sum problem in O(n^2) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity

Let A, B and C be three arrays of n integers each. I want to find 3 integers a,b,c s.t. a belongs to A, b belongs to B, c belongs to C and c=a+b.

Approach:

1. Calculate all possible sums a+b and store it in hash map. Time Complexity = O(n^2)
2. Parse through array C and  check if element is present in hash map or not.

This approach requires O(n^2) space and  O(n^2) time complexity. Can it be optimized to find a,b,c in O(n^2) time without extra space(ie- Space Complexity = O(1)) ?

Comment: Is it given that the arrays are sorted or anything like that?

Comment: Instead of storing the sums of each `a+b` (you did mean that, right?) you could convert C to a hashset, then check each `a+b`; this way it's at least down to O(n) space and O(n²) time. Similarly, if you sort C, you could use binary search for O(n² logn) time and O(1) space.

Comment: This is called the 3SUM problem; I don't think there is a known solution in O(n^2) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @Zabuzard arrays are NOT sorted

Comment: @kaya3 I think you know one.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes,it should be a+b, I have made the changes.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on 3SUM seems to include a [quadratic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm) (seems to be constant space, too) and a bit down how to apply that for 3 different array (instead of 3 numbers from the same array). Did not test or really try to understand it, though.

Comment: If you are allowed to mutate the arrays then it is possible, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have below approach for this. Is it correct ?

Algorithm:

```
 1. Sort A and B. Time complexity= O(nlgn) using  HeapSort
    2. Loop through elements of C
    2.1 Take 2 pointers one at beginning of A,
 second at end of B. Let this be left and right pointers
 and make left parse A and right parse B.

        2.2 if A[left] + B[right] == C[index] 
         then break
          else if A[left] + B[right] < C[index]
              left++;
          else
              right--;
```

Time complexity for step 2 = O(n^2)

Overall time complexity = O(n^2)

Space complexity = O(1)

Comment: @HeapOverflow Thanks, I will make the changes.

Comment: Doesn't randomized quicksort still take O(n^2) time and O(n) space?

Comment: Randomized quick sort worst time complexity is O(nlgn).check below post:https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35994/why-does-randomized-quicksort-have-on-log-n-worst-case-runtime-cost

Comment: We can use heap sort with O(nlgn) time complexity in wort case and O(1) space complexity.

Comment: That post doesn't say it's O(nlgn). But heapsort works, yes.